# Android Skipped 602 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android

i have this code below to ping a list of IPs in java Android but my problem now is the delay happening when i run and this problem shows up which says "Skipped 602 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. " can anyone suggest me a solution cause i am a beginner in android

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask t = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    synchronized (this)
                    {
                        try {
                            wait(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (ct < MyIps.length - 1) {
                                ct++;

                                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                                try {

                                    Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + MyIps[ct] );
                                    int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
                                    System.out.println("Value of   " + MyIps[ct] + " = " + exitValue);


                                    TableRow tableRow = findViewById(a[ct]);
                                    if (exitValue == 0)
                                    {
                                        tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border2);


                                    }

                                    else {

                                        tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);

                                    }
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            } else {

                                ct = -1;

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }


                }

        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t, 1000, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: You execute ipProcess.waitFor()` on the UI thread. That's a big no-no. Operations on the UI/main thread should be quick in-and-out affairs and the heavy lifting (such as network or disk I/O or even invoking external commands) should be done in a different thread. Funnily enough you *do* have a different thread (via the timer task) but instead of doing the heavy lifting there, you "switch back" to the UI thread to do it.

Comment: no need to say "Funnily" i said that i am a beginner in Android. if you can explain me more or advice me what exactly to do, i would be thankful @JoachimSauer

Comment: you have to make sure not to do heavy IO based operations (or long-running CPU-based operations) on the main thread. That probably means learning what the main thread is. For that I suggest Google.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem thanks to you. but now it takes about 10 second to ping each IP, ,is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score -1):

Your computer configuration is very low. And the android studio is a ram eating monster. Moreover, you opened an emulator. More ram is consumed. Normally your emulator will be lagging. If you use video or gif then you can clearly see. Much like youtube buffering. Try avoiding emulator. Use a physical device for developing. Then you will not see this type of warning. High-end pc will not have this type of warning. If your pc is already high end, then increase the ram size of the emulator. Otherwise use a physical device.